# How can I install 32-bit libraries on Elementary OS 6 Odin?

Tags: release-odin, elementary-project, steam

I did download Steam its website and install it on Elementary OS 6 Odin but when I tried to start it, it gives an error "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libGL.so.1, libdrm.so2"

Comment: Usually Steam will install those on the first load. We’re you asked for your Elementary password when starting Steam?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable i386 architecture.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt update
```

After this, the Steam installation should be able to pull all i386 dependencies.